# Как решить эту задачу программным путем(Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Из пункта A в пункт B одновременно стартовали два лыжника. Скорость первого x метров в секунду, скорость второго y метров в секунду. Известно, что x>y. Одновременно с ними, из пункта B им навстречу стартовал третий лыжник, который движется со скоростью z метров в секунду. В какой-то момент третий лыжник встретил первого, а ровно через t секунд после этого встретил второго.
Требуется выяснить, через сколько секунд после встречи со вторым лыжником третий прибудет в пункт A.

**Input format**

В одной строке через пробел записано четыре числа x, y, z, и t.
x строго больше y, все числа целые из отрезка от 1 до 1000.

**Output format**

Вывести одно вещественное число - ответ на задачу с точностью не меньше трёх знаков после десятичной точки.

**Примеры:**

Input
5 4 10 100

Output
600

Input
342 221 2 747

Output
234669.12397

Comment: Решить аналитически, потом запрограммировать.

Comment: дайте фулл пожалуйста я не программист

Answer (score 5, accepted):

задача на уровне 6-7 классов :)

пусть расстояние между пунктами `L`, тогда

1. надо найти через сколько встретятся `x` и `z`
2. узнать какое расстояние будет между `x` и `y` к этому времени
3. зная это расстояние, узнать через какое время встретятся `z` и `y`
4. поскольку это время известно, то через него и 1) - 3) выразить `L`
5. а зная расстояние уже несложно вычислить и искомое время как

   ```
    Tитог = Tz - Tвстр - t
   ```

где `Tz` - время за которое `z` проёдёт все расстояние, `Tвстр` - время встречи с `x`, а `t` - время встречи с `y` после этого

**Итоговый код:**

```
t_res = ? * ? * (? + ?) / (? * (? - ?))
print(t_res)
```

Comment: Надо в таких случаях давать удочку, а не рыбу. Человек не будет учиться если уж и такие простые вещи за него решить. Подсказать - как - да.. Но не решать за него, если он просто даже не пробовал. Ну мне так кажется.

Comment: @NykSu, я пробовал и не раз, и после такого легкого решения считаю себя совсем глупым, и хотя я просил дать только подсказку, я очень благодарю автора за полный ответ.

Comment: согласен - скорректировал

Comment: @Zhihar, спасибо, твой ответ очень помог, в итоге ушло всего пять минут на код, теперь чувствую себя полным идиотом.